# Join view function postgresql using typeorm nest js

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am accessing the database from another application. I created two views as entity in Nest Js, namely 'view_user' and 'view_profile.' Is it possible to join the 'view_user' with 'view_profile,' similar to joining tables in a typical type ORM? Below is the method I used to join these two views, but I encountered an error message like this:

> Relation UsersView.profiles does not have join columns.

usersView

```
import { JoinColumn, OneToMany, ViewColumn, ViewEntity } from 'typeorm';
import { ProfilesView } from 'src/modules/profiles/entity/profiles.entity';

@ViewEntity({
    name: 'view_users',
    expression: `SELECT * FROM users`,
})
export class UsersView {
    @ViewColumn() id: number;
    @ViewColumn() userName: string;
    @ViewColumn() email: string;
    @ViewColumn() phoneNumber: string;
    @ViewColumn() createdAt: Date;
    @ViewColumn() updatedAt: Date;
    @ViewColumn() phoneCountryCode: string;
    @ViewColumn() deletedAt: Date;
    @ViewColumn() isBlacklist: boolean;
    @ViewColumn() fcmNotificationId: string;

    @OneToMany(() => ProfilesView, (profiles) => profiles.user)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'userId', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
    profiles: ProfilesView[];
}
```

ProfilesView

```
import { JoinColumn, ManyToOne, ViewColumn, ViewEntity } from 'typeorm';
import { UsersView } from 'src/modules/users/entity/users.entity';

@ViewEntity({
    name: 'view_profiles',
    expression: `SELECT * FROM profile`,
})
export class ProfilesView {
    @ViewColumn() id: number;
    @ViewColumn() name: string;
    @ViewColumn() gender: string;
    @ViewColumn() phoneNumber: string;
    @ViewColumn() phoneCountryCode: string;
    @ViewColumn() email: string;
    @ViewColumn() identityCardNumber: string;
    @ViewColumn() isPatient: number;
    @ViewColumn() birthDate: Date;
    @ViewColumn() userId: number;
    @ViewColumn() unlocked: number;
    @ViewColumn() linked: number;
    @ViewColumn() createdAt: Date;
    @ViewColumn() updatedAt: Date;
    @ViewColumn() bpjsCardNumber: string;
    @ViewColumn() hasBpjs: number;
    @ViewColumn() deletedAt: Date;

    @ManyToOne(() => UsersView, (user) => user.profiles)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'userId' })
    user: UsersView;
}
```

UsersService

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ILike, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { PageRequestDto } from 'src/common/request/request.options.dto';
import { UsersView } from './entity/users.entity';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(UsersView)
        private repository: Repository<UsersView>,
    ) {}

    async getData(request: PageRequestDto) {
        const { limit, page, orderBy, orderType, search, searchBy } = request;

        const result = await this.repository.find({
            where: {
                ...(search && { phoneNumber: ILike(`%${search.trim()}%`) }),
            },
            ...(page && { skip: (page - 1) * limit }),
            ...(limit && { take: limit }),
            order: {
                ...(orderBy && { [orderBy]: orderType ? orderType : 'DESC' }),
                ...(!orderBy && { id: orderType ? orderType : 'DESC' }),
            },
            relations: {
                profiles: true,
            },
        });

        const count = await this.repository.count({
            where: {
                ...(search && { phoneNumber: ILike(`%${search.trim()}%`) }),
            },
        });
        return { result: result, count: count };
    }
}
```

This is my expected data result from join the view

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        phoneNumber: 'xxxx', 
        profile: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'xxx'
            }, 
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'xxx'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        phoneNumber: 'xxxx', 
        profile: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'xxx'
            }, 
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'xxx'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only have the JoinColumn decorator on one side of the relation (the "many" side in many-to-one). So you should have this in your ProfilesView

```js
    @ManyToOne(() => UsersView, (user) => user.profiles)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'userId', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
    user: UsersView;
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I've been doing it this way since the first time, its give me another error in query, the error says : "syntax error at or near \",\"", but in this case I solved it in another way, namely just joining 2 tables in one view, and taking data from the relational table as objects with the json_agg() and json_build_object() functions in the query

Comment: I think you should be able to avoid having to do that. I found this github issue that seems to have the correct solution to this actually: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4228

Even if this doesn't work you can definitely do a join between views in the query builder like so: 



usersViewRepo.createQueryBuilder('u')
  .innerJoinAndSelect(ProfilesView, 'p', 'p.userId = u.id')
  .getMany();